# Guard expressions in Erlang: using "and" vs using "comma"

Tags: erlang

I have just started learning Erlang but I can't figure out why this code doesn't match the function call test:sum(3)

```
-module(test).
-export([sum/1]).

sum(0) -> 0;
sum(N) when is_integer(N) and N>0 -> N + sum(N - 1).
```

... while this does:

```
-module(test).
-export([sum/1]).

sum(0) -> 0;
sum(N) when is_integer(N), N>0 -> N + sum(N - 1).
```

Am I missing something about the two different approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of the operator precedence.

As defined in the [reference](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id84170), operator `and` comes before `>`, so what you actually get in your first code snippet is:

```
sum(N) when (is_integer(N) and N)>0 -> N + sum(N - 1).
```

So in your case you are comparing `(true and 3) > 0`, which can't be true, that's why your guard never matches.

To fix this you can write your guard this way:

```
sum(N) when (is_integer(N)) and (N>0) -> N + sum(N - 1).
```

P.S. Parentheses for `is_integer/1` are not necessary in this scenario, but it might look clearer this way.

Comment: btw, is_integer (N) can not take in brackets

Comment: Also, `and` doesn't short curcuit (as `,` does) so `andalso` should be preferred instead.